# Mobile App - Simple Bar Chart

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, mobile, charts

The requirement is to build a mobile app that display a simple bar chart with a set of (x,y) values.

The last time I dabbled with mobile app was like 2-3 years when Mobile SDK was at its infancy.

Is there an easy way to build the requirement with Salesforce1/Lightning component or I should build a VF page for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest just use Lightning component framework and build a lightning component .

Or you can also build a simple responsive page and plug as an Salesforce 1 tab .

Also there is Chartjs lightning component for free at appexchange and you can just use that as well and build your Bar chart

https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000000q5ADEAY

I dont see any need for a Mobile Native app with SDK unless the User wants to store offline data .Also even in this case a hybrid app can do .